# Matching query does not exist. DRF

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Okay I have been at this for a while and cannot figure it out. Whenever I make a new job post I get the following error

jobs.models.Positions.DoesNotExist: Positions matching query does not exist.

Business Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_google_maps import fields as map_fields

from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
Company = settings.COMPANY_USER_MODEL

class Business(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True) 

    address = map_fields.AddressField(max_length=200, null=True)
    geolocation = map_fields.GeoLocationField(max_length=100, null=True) 
    about = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.business
```

Job Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_google_maps import fields as map_fields
import uuid as uuid_lib

from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Positions(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position


class Job(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey('business.Business', related_name='jobs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Positions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    address = map_fields.AddressField(max_length=200, null=True)
    geolocation = map_fields.GeoLocationField(max_length=100, null=True)

    uuid = models.UUIDField(db_index=True, default=uuid_lib.uuid4, editable=False)

    job_detail = models.TextField()  # TODO: set length

    full_time = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    part_time = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

Job Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers, fields
from .models import Job, Type, Positions

def get_business_model():
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.BUSINESS_MODEL, require_ready=False)


Business = get_business_model()


# Position Serializer
class PositionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Positions
        fields = "__all__"
    
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_posted = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True, format='%B %w, %Y')

    position = serializers.CharField(source="position.position")
    business = serializers.CharField(source="business.business")

    def create(self, validated_data):
    position = validated_data.pop('position')
    position_instance = Positions.objects.get(position=position)

    business = validated_data.pop('business')
    business_instance = Business.objects.get(business=business)

    return Job.objects.create(position=position_instance, business=business_instance, **validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        exclude = ['employer', ]
        depth = 1
```

Job Views:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, generics
from rest_framework.mixins import UpdateModelMixin
from .serializer import JobSerializer, PositionSerializer
from .models import Job, User, Positions


class JobListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        # permissions.IsAuthenticated
        permissions.AllowAny  # TODO: change authorization
    ]
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
            serializer.save(employer=self.request.user)


class JobRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        # permissions.IsAuthenticated
        permissions.AllowAny  # TODO: change authorization
    ]
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'


class PositionsAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = PositionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Positions.objects.all()
        position = self.request.GET.get('position')

        if position is not None:
            position = queryset.filter(position__istartswith=position)[:5]

            return position
```

I am using this in combination with React and Redux but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I believe it is my serializer. The objects definitely do exist because when I hardcode one of them in it finds it no problem and gets posted

like if I do the following it will work

```
def create(self, validated_data):
position_instance = Positions.objects.get(position='Bartender')
business_instance = Business.objects.get(business='lameee')

return Job.objects.create(position=position_instance,   business=business_instance, **validated_data)
```

Postman request
[image]

My database
[image]
[image]

Thank You :)

Comment: are you sure you connect to the same database?

Answer (score 0):

Wow so after weeks of struggling with this I figured it out. All I had to do was change

business = serializers.CharField(source="business.business")

and

position = serializers.CharField(source="position.position")

to

position = serializers.CharField()

and

business = serializers.CharField()

Job Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers, fields
from .models import Job, Type, Positions

def get_business_model():
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.BUSINESS_MODEL, require_ready=False)


Business = get_business_model()


# Position Serializer
class PositionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Positions
        fields = "__all__"
    
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_posted = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True, format='%B %w, %Y')

    position = serializers.CharField()
    business = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
    position = validated_data.pop('position')
    position_instance = Positions.objects.get(position=position)

    business = validated_data.pop('business')
    business_instance = Business.objects.get(business=business)

    return Job.objects.create(position=position_instance, business=business_instance, **validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        exclude = ['employer', ]
        depth = 1
```